# Consider $ \ A \cap (B-C)$ and $ \ (A\cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question:

Consider $ \ A \cap (B-C)$ and $ \ (A\cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Are the two sets equal or is one a subset of the other?

My attempt:

We know that if $ \ x\in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C) \implies x \in A \cap B$ and $ \ x \notin A \cap C \implies x \in A$ and $ \ x\in B$ and $ \ x\notin C \implies x \in A $and $ \ x\in B-C \implies x \in A \cap (B-C)$

So, $ \ (A\cap B) - (A \cap C) \subseteq \ A \cap (B-C) $

Is the other way true?

Comment: Could you please show me how to prove the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x\in \ A\cap (B -C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B-C$ (so $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$).

Now $x\in A\cap B$ (since $x\in A$ and $x\in B$) and $x\notin A\cap C$ (since $x\notin C$).

So $x\in \ (A\cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Since $x$ is arbitrary we have $A\cap (B-C)\subseteq \ (A\cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Through logic it should be true using definition $\forall x: x\in (X-A) \iff (x \in X) \land (x \notin A)$  that

$$\forall x: (x \in A) \land ((x \in B) \land (x\notin C)) =\forall x:  ((x \in A) \land (x \in B)) \land ((x \notin C) \lor (x\notin A))$$

because in order to satisfy the formula, $x$ must be in $A$, therefore $(x \notin A)$ is always false and the rightmost term is false, meaning that $(x \notin C) \lor (x\notin A)$ is the same as $(x \notin C)$

Answer (score 1):

Another way of proving the equality of the sets is:

\begin{align} (A\cap B)-(A\cap C) &= (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)^c \\&= (A\cap B)\cap (A^c\cup C^c)\\&=((A\cap B)\cap A^c) \cup ((A\cap B)\cap C^c) \\&= ((A\cap A^c)\cap B)\cup(A\cap (B\cap C^c))\\&=(\emptyset\cap B)\cup(A\cap(B-C)) \\&= \emptyset\cup(A\cap(B-C))\\&=A\cap(B-C) \end{align}

This way, you don't need the two directions, since all equalities go both ways.

---

I used the rules:

- Commutativity and associativity of $\cap, \cup$
- Distributivity among $\cap$ and $\cup$ (i.e., $X\cap(Y\cup Z) = (X\cap Y)\cup(X\cap Z)$
- Definition of $X-Y$ as $X-Y=X\cap Y^c$ (where $Y^c$ is the *complement* of $Y$.